# hierarchical/vertical tree layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, data-visualization

I'm trying to find an effective JavaScript library that can help to create a vertical tree layout something like this

```
  Item
    |
    | SubI1    SubI2
    |  |         |
    |  |__....   |__....
    |__|         |
    |            |___.....
    |____________|
    |
    |...
```

Also these items could be added with click events to perform collapse/expand on their children. Is there any references that you guys could recommend?

Comment: which ones have you tried already?

Comment: I have seen some samples on d3, jquery and seems like d3 would fit with my purpose